# Where are shell_exec 'echos' saved in?

Tags: php, linux, stdout, stdin, shell-exec

I'm running a web server frontend that has numerous php console scripts (run via shell_exec) embedded throughout the backend.

These are triggered from `shell_exec(php $scripthere);`

These scripts have useful information output from them, such as `echo "You should read this";` and `die("You should read this too");` but as they are never echo'd to the frontend, they are never displayed.

Running my Ubuntu server, where can I read the outputs from shell_exec? Yes I know I could go through every line of code and fputs it somewhere, but as this is run via the shell_exec command is there not some STDOUT file or something I could read all outputs from?

Comment: They are echo'd to STDOUT and STDERR in the shell because you are performing `shell_exec()`

Comment: `shell_exec` returns the output the command wrote to stdout as a string. You could redirect the output directly in the command to a file or use a function that offers you a bit more freedom when it comes to this.

Comment: Quickest hack I can think of is to [override](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) shell_exec to throw the output to syslog(), or something similar. Bear in mind if you *do* go through every line of code and fputs it somewhere you'll need to deal with the possibility of concurrent writes to that file triggered by multiple simultaneous users, and the very real possibility of blocking on that file write if you're under heavy load.